# Get count of items and their values in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider these Tables:

```
Table Items:

ItemID    ItemName
------------------
 1          N1
 2          N2 
 3          N4
 4          N5
```

and in MyTbl table I have a ItemID that may be like this:

```
ItemId
----
1
1
3
4
4
4
```

I want to write a query that return this result:

```
ItemId        count
-------------------
   1            2
   2            0
   3            1
   4            3
```

How I can do this without Cursors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select every item from `Items` and `LEFT JOIN` `MyTbl` on the common `ItemID`, counting the matches;

```
select 
   Items.itemId,
   count(MyTbl.itemId) as count
from Items
   left join MyTbl on (MyTbl.ItemID = Items.ItemID)
group by Items.itemId
order by Items.itemId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @Items as table(ItemID int,ItemName varchar(20))
declare @MyTbl as table(ItemId int)

insert into  @Items values(1, 'N1')
insert into  @Items values(2, 'N2') 
insert into  @Items values(3, 'N4')
insert into  @Items values(4, 'N5')

insert into @MyTbl values(1)
insert into @MyTbl values(1)
insert into @MyTbl values(3)
insert into @MyTbl values(4)
insert into @MyTbl values(4)
insert into @MyTbl values(4)

select I.ItemID, COUNT(M.ItemId) as [COUNT] from  @Items I left outer join @MyTbl M on I.ItemID = M.ItemId
    group by I.ItemID
```