# Count specific items in one column

Tags: sql

I have a table called `ratings`, and a column called `item_id`. I simply would like to group each individual item together and count them.

For example:

if there are 1000 rows, and `item_id` 51 has been rated 20 times, and `item_id` 14 has been rated 7 times and `item_id` 33 has been rated 2 times, I simply want it to be grouped in `DESC` like:

item_id 51
item_id 7
item_id 33

I tried to follow something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307808/get-count-of-items-and-their-values-in-one-column), but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM ratings 
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT item_id, COUNT(rating) AS rating
    FROM ratings GROUP BY item_id
) a
GROUP BY a.rating DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*) AS counter, item_id
FROM ratings
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY counter DESC
```